# Easy to set up docker-compose hosting

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hosting, web-hosting

I am trying to find an easy to set up docker hosting. What I have is a private git repository with an application, that I can get running locally just with checking it out and running `docker-compose up -d`. I am not at the moment looking for a production-ready solution, just for a way to get it running somewhere so that few of the potential customers can see the progress, paly with the app a little and suggest improvements. So any service where it is not too much hassle to get it running and accessible from the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution 1

You could use [play-with-docker](https://labs.play-with-docker.com/) . This is a **free** online docker environment accessible via web. The docker-compose tool is also available. The only downside is that the environment will expire after 4 hours. An other similar free online service is also [katacoda](https://www.katacoda.com/).

#### Solution 2

Create AWS account and deploy a linux VM in the free tier. The free tier enable you to create a VM with limited resources for one year.

#### Solution 3

Prepare a virtual box VM with everyting is needed to run your application.

If you need I can provide further details about the above solutions.